# tracking pixel image src multiple times on one page

Tags: html, browser-cache, cache-control

I have an opt in service and every time there is a new opt-in this tracking pixel needs to be executed. Right now there is a cron job running every minute checking for new opt-ins and how ever many new opt-ins there are when the scrip is run it places this tracking pixel on the page that many times. The problem is even though the tracking pixel image is on the page multiple times it is only being executed once. I have tried to disable the cache with the headers but no luck. Is there a way to have an instance for each image on a page be downloaded separately instead of only once?

Answer (score 1):

Specify a HTTP headers indicating that request should not be cached (`Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate`) and use randomized query as cache buster.

Comment: I already tried that with this:
<?php 
  header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
  header("Pragma: no-cache");
  header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
?> 
and it still did't work

Comment: That depends on if server actually lets you generate those from PHP. Check what you really get in browser with its network traffic monitor (most browsers have one by now). Also, use cache buster too, as I've mentioned.